# How to specify target ABI in cmake?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, centos, abi

I'm not sure if my question is correct. But I've got an legacy project which is compiled by cmake into shared library with `System V` ABI:

```
$ readelf -a -W /path/to/my/lib/libname.so | grep 'OS/ABI:'
  OS/ABI:                            UNIX - System V
```

But I need it to be `UNIX - GNU`. How can I make it?

My OS is CentOS. I've tested a hello-world-library compilations and it's `UNIX - GNU` on this machine.

Comment: `brandelf` utility?

Comment: @arrowd looks interesting. But it's for FreeBSD. Are there any alternatives for CentOS (RedHat)?

Comment: brandelf can still usually run on Linux systems, irregardless of its origin.